# Expected 4-dimensional input for 4-dimensional weight [64, 1, 3, 3], but got 2-dimensional input of size [18560, 79] instead

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, size, ocr

I'm trying to train on TPSSpatialTransformationNetwork. My input image size is (32,128). After running this code below, I got an error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQVHO.png)

I can not figure out the shape of the tensor in the error message. Here is the code:

```
class TPS_SpatialTransformerNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TPS_SpatialTransformerNetwork, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 79, kernel_size=5)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(79, 256, kernel_size=5)
        self.conv2_drop = nn.Dropout2d()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(256, 512)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(512, 79)

        # Spatial transformer localization-network
        self.localization = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(1, 8, kernel_size=7),
            nn.MaxPool2d(2, stride=2),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.Conv2d(8, 79, kernel_size=5),
            nn.MaxPool2d(2, stride=2),
            nn.ReLU(True)
        )

        # Regressor for the 3 * 2 affine matrix
        self.fc_loc = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(79 * 4 * 28, 32),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.Linear(32, 3 * 2)
        )

        # Initialize the weights/bias with identity transformation
        self.fc_loc[2].weight.data.zero_()
        self.fc_loc[2].bias.data.copy_(torch.tensor([1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], dtype=torch.float))

    # Spatial transformer network forward function
    def stn(self, x):
        xs = self.localization(x)
        xs = xs.view(-1, 79 * 4 * 28)
        theta = self.fc_loc(xs)
        theta = theta.view(-1, 2, 3)


        grid = F.affine_grid(theta, x.size())
        x = F.grid_sample(x, grid)

        return x

    def forward(self, x):
        # transform the input
        x = self.stn(x)

        # Perform the usual forward pass
        x = F.relu(F.max_pool2d(self.conv1(x), 2))
        x = F.relu(F.max_pool2d(self.conv2_drop(self.conv2(x)), 2))
        x = x.view(-1, 256)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.dropout(x, training=self.training)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return F.log_softmax(x, dim=1)
```

Comment: Please post the entire error message.

Comment: RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-8e4080ab93b4> in <module>()
     31 
     32                # compute outputs and loss
---> 33                outputs = model(inputs)
     34                loss = ctc_loss(outputs, targets, torch.full((len(inputs),), 32, dtype=torch.int32), seq_lengths)
     35

Comment: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py in _conv_forward(self, input, weight, bias)
    394                             _pair(0), self.dilation, self.groups)
    395         return F.conv2d(input, weight, bias, self.stride,
--> 396                         self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)
    397 
    398     def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:

RuntimeError: Expected 4-dimensional input for 4-dimensional weight [64, 1, 3, 3], but got 2-dimensional input of size [18560, 79] instead

Comment: please help me :<

Comment: Please post updates as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67497040/edit) to the question, and properly formatted, not as a comment.

Comment: I've edited it.

Comment: What shape is the data being input into your model? It's expecting an image (batch_size, channels, H,W).

Comment: the shape of the input data is (128,1,32,128)

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1pXh9dinALCO-uynDSvaBNpMPEDpAFe_P  here is all my code, pls help me :<

Comment: You network is working fine with input shape of `(128, 1, 32, 128)` and giving output of `[18560, 79]` what is the error ?

Comment: it keeps saying that "Expected 4-dimensional input for 4-dimensional weight [64, 1, 3, 3], but got 2-dimensional input of size [18560, 79] instead"

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1pXh9dinALCO-uynDSvaBNpMPEDpAFe_P. Here is the code of all 4 stages in the model :<. The error comes from tranformation module right?

Comment: Please read this : https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  The code you provided in the question does not cause any issue. Please add **all code** required to reproduce the problem you face **in the question itself** , and remove code that is unrelated. For example you TPS_SpatialStuff network has no issue at all, so it should be edited out. In theory, one would like to be able to copypaste your code in their IDE and have the exact same error yielded. Please add the **whole** stack trace as well